# What i missed in this socket get with parameters? (windows sockets)

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, winsock2

I have the following get request in **windows**.
i'm trying to figure out why i not get a response.

I'm pretty sure that the error is in get request string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

#pragma warning(disable: 4996)//for winsock

int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
            std::cout << "WSAStartup failed.\n";
            system("pause");
            return 1;
        }

    SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        struct hostent *host;
        host = gethostbyname("www.google.com");
        SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
        SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
        SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
        std::cout << "Connecting...\n";
        if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
                return 1;
        }


    char *httpRequest = "GET /get\r\nHost:www.google.com?uuid=2010010\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

    send(Socket, httpRequest, strlen(httpRequest), 0);
        char buffer[10000];
        int nDataLength;

        while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0)) > 0){
            int i = 0;
            while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
                i += 1;
            }
        }

    if (nDataLength > 0)
            std::cout << "Received GET response";
        else 
            std::cout << "NOT GET response: size = 0";
        std::cout<<buffer;
        closesocket(Socket);
        WSACleanup();
}
```

All I get in the page is the html code... I don't understand why I don't receive a response

Comment: Better use a real HTTP client library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/); see references and advices [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34850854/841108)

Comment: How do you know that you only get the HTML? There is no output in above code snippet. Also, what is the inner `while` loop for? Please post an [mcve] so that the issue can be reproduced easily. Adding a `main()` function along with socket creation code should not be much larger than the above code.

Comment: I assume you have the inner loop to skip leading white-space? But that `buffer[i] >= 32` condition will mean it skips just about everything.

Comment: Oh, and you should probably try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And tell us what is the true purpose of that inner loop, and also tell us *how* you know you don't get a header.

Comment: By the way, just because `nDataLength != 0` is false doesn't mean `nDataLength` is zero. It might as well be `-1` which means you have an error.

Comment: I have added a complete exeample

Comment: In the outer while loop, you are overwriting the buffer in each iteration.

Comment: nop. this is how it is work receive

Comment: It's always good to know what language you are programming in - this is C++, not C. Please retag.

Comment: i had retaged from c to c++

Comment: What is the basis for your expectation that you should receive something other than HTML? NB Neither your original GET request nor the change mentioned in your first comment about HTTP 1.1 is legal HTTP. If you're going to implement HTTP you need to get it right. Have a good look at RFC 2616. And why aren't you using an HTTP library?

Comment: because i should receive some text in json format.

Comment: i only want to send a get with some parameters. How difficult is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing HTTP version on the first line of  your request.

it should end with `HTTP/1.1`

or leave off the version and the other headers and just go with version 0.9

Comment: i have added  "HTTP/1.1 GET /get\r\nHost:" but did not worked

Comment: @user5692672 *This is wrong, I was mistaken, see @immibis below*. Just FYI: `\r\n` is the Windows way of doing newlines. Pick a random public HTTP server and chances are it's running a Linux distro, where you just use `\n` instead. Don't know if that's the reason why you're having problems, but thought you should know.

Comment: @szczurcio ***WRONG*** (excessive emphasis there, but just to make sure readers see this). The HTTP standard always uses \r\n. See section 3 of [the RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230).

Comment: @immibis Oh, my bad then. Thanks for the info.

Comment: most text basted internet protocols use \r\n  - I can't think of any exceptions.

Comment: please try the example. it is full functional. the problem is it in http request and is not \r\n

Comment: can't do that easily enough.  linux here.  your code started out looking fairly generic but then turned out to be winsock code.  that while loop at the end will discard the start of the response if the response is big enough.